# Create new records in one table-A and add as foreign key to table-B if the foreign key field in table-B is null -PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table A and Table B look like shown below. The intention is to write an SQL script to run and update the tables. Table B has a foreign key to Table-A. If the field is null in Table B, then create a new record in Table-A and update Table B with that foreign key

[image: Table A and Table B]

It is expected to add two new records in Table A and add those foreign key in the Table B as per the above example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the IDs in any way auto-generated? How about showing us the `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: How do you know which FK value to put in each Table B record?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  yes, it is UUID. here just shown dummy values

Comment: @NickW that is the challenge here. there is no related fields to match.

Comment: I'm confused. If you don't know the correct values (or the rules to determine them) to put in the table how do you expect anyone else to know? Or do you just want to create a random record in Table A and update every record, with null a_id, in Table B with a reference to the Table A record?

Comment: @NickW  Sorry if I didn't communicate properly. 
Table A will have random entries, and then update the id to Table B. 
but first we  need to select the entries in Table B which have null values and from there insert the values into Table A , and then update Table B with the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote for you sample for do it.
But I don't know your business logic detail. You can change some solutions.

```
CREATE TABLE tablea (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tablea_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tableb (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    a_id int4 NULL,
    "name" varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tableb_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tableb (id, a_id, "name") VALUES(1, 100, 'b1');
INSERT INTO tableb (id, a_id, "name") VALUES(2, NULL, 'b2');
INSERT INTO tableb (id, a_id, "name") VALUES(3, NULL, 'b3');
INSERT INTO tableb (id, a_id, "name") VALUES(4, NULL, 'b4');

-- create function for inserting data into tablea and returning these id

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tablea_inserting()
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$   
declare 
    ret int4;
begin 
    insert into tablea ("name") values ('test')
    returning id into ret; 

    return ret;  
end 
$function$
;

-- After then you can update your tableb
update tableb set 
a_id = tablea_inserting()
where a_id is null

select * from tableb;
Result: 
id  a_id    name
1   100     b1
2   1       b2
3   2       b3
4   3       b4
```